# Correct way to parse date

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to parse the following date ut get a runtime error saying:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-11-21-05:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10
```

My input:

```
String inpDate = "2019-11-20-05:00"
```

I also tried the following date formats but no luck.

`yyyy-MM-ddZ`

`yyyy-MM-dd Z`

Code:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
public static final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(inpDate, dateFormatter);
return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

How can I get my input to parse correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-ddZZZZZ";
```

It has 5 times the letter "Z". To parse a timezone offset with a colon, you need to provide the letter "Z" 5 times. This may be somewhat hidden away in the Javadoc.

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> **Offset Z**: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>
> One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero.
>
> Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero.
>
> ***Five letters*** outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, **with colon**.
>
> It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

It’s easier than you think. The formatter you need is built in. So don’t struggle with writing your own format pattern string.

```
    String inpDate = "2019-11-20-05:00";
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(inpDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
    System.out.println(Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

Output in my time zone:

> Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 EST 2019

I am assuming that you are only converting to a `Date` because you need one for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now. Otherwise you should not use `Date` but stick to the modern API.

### Start of day in your time zone or at the offset given in the string?

**Edit:** Basil Bourque in a comment asked this very knowledgeable question:

> Perhaps it would be more true to the intent of the publisher of this
>   input string to get the first moment of the day as seen in that offset
>   of 5 hours behind UTC. Is it possible to parse as an `OffsetDateTime`
>   with the time-of-day defaulting to first moment of the day (00:00:00)?
>   (And then convert to `java.util.Date` if required.)

It’s definitely true. I have chosen to give code that gives the result that I think the code in the question was trying to obtain. If we understand `2019-11-20-05:00` as some unspecified time in the half-open interval from 2019-11-20T00:00-05:00 to 2019-11-21T00:00-05:00, then for some offsets and some default time zones the result from the above code snippet will actually lie *outside* that interval (typically before it, may also in corner cases fall after it). So this is true to the question (if I understood it correctly) and untrue to the publisher of the original string. If instead we want the start of day at the UTC offset given in the string I would go like this:

```
    TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse(inpDate);
    Instant startOfDayAtSpecifiedOffset = LocalDate.from(parsed)
            .atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.from(parsed))
            .toInstant();
    System.out.println(Date.from(startOfDayAtSpecifiedOffset));
```

Output in my time zone:

> Wed Nov 20 06:00:00 CET 2019

I am at offset +01:00 in November, which is why the time here is 06:00 when the day begins at offset -05:00. To illustrate that the choice of time zone or offset may make a great difference, here’s the output from running the latter snippet with Pacific/Kiritimati as default time zone:

> Wed Nov 20 19:00:00 LINT 2019

Or in Pacific/Pago_Pago time zone:

> Tue Nov 19 18:00:00 SST 2019

So pick carefully what you really want.

### What went wrong in your code?

First, `LocalDate.parse()` and similar parsing methods insist on parsing the entire string or they will throw the exception you saw mentioning `unparsed text found at index (some index)` (you may use the overloaded `DateTimeFormatter.parse​(CharSequence, ParsePosition)` method for parsing only as much as possible of the string without that exception).

Second, one `Z` in the format pattern string matches offset without colon, so `-0500`, not `-05:00`.

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.parse​(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.text.ParsePosition))

Answer (score 0):

```
        String inpDate = "2019-11-20-05:00";
        System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(inpDate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm")));
```

Will print 2019-11-20.

Comment: This is incorrect. If `05:00` is a time of day, you need uppercase `HH` for the hour of day. But it probably isn’t. I take `-05:00` to be a UTC offset. A date without time of day and with offset is peculiar, but it is sometimes used, I haven’t really understood what for.

Comment: The hour (or time offset if that is what it is) did not seem to be needed since they only wanted the date. So I just made something that would parse it, HH is probably better though.